# Use of NSSet to hold a list of delegates in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, design-patterns

I am writing a component (e.g. `VeryLongJobExecuter`) in Objective C.

I want this `VeryLongJobExecuter` to be able to notify other objects (`one to many`) when its job is finished, and execute a common method, e.g. (`jobExecuted`).

I am thinking to store the reference of these delegates in either NSArray/NSSet, and iterate the delegates and call the method.

Or should I use Notification instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that we have notifications is so that you don't have to keep a reference to every other object that might care about an event.  Don't re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

Notification was done for that purpose so I would use that instead.